# Somar o valor inteiro de uma lista com outra. EX: [9,9,9,9]+[0,0,0,1]=[10,0,0,0]

Tags: python

Tudo bom, pessoal?!

Estou com problemas para implementar algo do tipo(em python):

Tenho listas, por exemplo:

```
Lista1 = [9,9,9,9]
Lista2 = [0,0,0,1]
```

Quero uma saída com algo do tipo: **[10,0,0,0]**(lista soma)

Tipo o 9 + 1 (da última posição), vira 10(óbvio) o 1 sobe pra posição anterior da lista1, somando com o próximo 9, e o 0 assume a última posição da lista soma, adição simples.

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço :)

*Obs: a entrada(de qualquer tamanho) é data pelo usuário. Aí no caso eu li uma string(de números), 'splitei' ela número por número e transformei eles em inteiros.*

Comment: Mais fácil operar como dois inteiros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem entrar no mérito de que esta não é uma boa maneira de somar números (estou assumindo que é apenas para fins de aprendizado da linguagem), uma ideia é usar [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) para percorrer do último para o primeiro dígito, e [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para percorrer ambas as listas ao mesmo tempo.

Aí, basta somar os dígitos, e caso a soma seja maior que 9, acumule o valor para a próxima iteração:

```
lista1 = [9, 9, 9, 9]
lista2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
acc = 0
result = []
for d1, d2 in zip(reversed(lista1), reversed(lista2)):
    soma = d1 + d2 + acc
    result.insert(0, soma % 10) # insere sempre no início da lista
    acc = soma // 10

if acc > 0: # se ainda tem algum valor acumulado
    result[0] += 10 * acc
print(result) # [10, 0, 0, 0]
```

Também não entendi porque o resultado não deveria ser `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (para manter a regra de ter um dígito para cada elemento da lista), mas enfim (se fosse para fazer isso, bastaria trocar `result[0] += 10 * acc` por `result.insert(0, acc)`).

---

Só não ficou claro se as listas sempre têm o mesmo tamanho. Por exemplo, se for digitado "1", a lista seria apenas `[1]` ou `[0, 0, 0, 1]`? Mas como você saberá a quantidade de zeros a serem acrescentados? Pois só dará para saber disso depois de ler todos os números.

Enfim, se quiser ser mais genérico, sugiro usar `zip_longest`, que itera por listas de tamanhos diferentes, e ainda tem a opção de adicionar o zero para os valores faltantes:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lista1 = [9, 9, 9, 9]
lista2 = [1]

acc = 0
result = []
for digitos in zip_longest(reversed(lista1), reversed(lista2), fillvalue=0):
    acc, digito = divmod(sum(digitos) + acc, 10)
    result.insert(0, digito)

if acc > 0:
    result[0] += 10 * acc
print(result) # [10, 0, 0, 0]
```

Também usei [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) para já ter o resultado da divisão e o resto desta mesma divisão, tudo de uma vez (apenas para mostrar outra forma de fazer), além de [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) para somar os dígitos.

---

Desta forma, daria para fazer de uma maneira bem mais genérica, que some vários números de uma vez:

```
numeros = []
while True: # ler vários números
    n = input('digite o número (ou zero para encerrar): ')
    # não estou validando se é número mesmo
    if n == '0': break

    # transforma cada dígito do número em um elemento da lista
    numeros.append(list(map(int, n)))

# ao final do while, "numeros" é uma lista contendo várias listas (e cada uma representa um número)

from itertools import zip_longest

acc = 0
result = []
for digitos in zip_longest(*map(reversed, numeros), fillvalue=0):
    acc, digito = divmod(sum(digitos) + acc, 10)
    result.insert(0, digito)

if acc > 0:
    result[0] += 10 * acc
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado. Peço desculpa pela formulação da pergunta, pode ter sido confusa mesmo. Quanto ao mérito da funcionalidade da questão, é coisa de professor, definitivamente eu sei que esse não é nem de longe o método mais simples ou melhor para solucionar o problema.
Enfim, vou melhorar a formulação das minhas perguntas na comunidade, sou novo aqui. 
Me ajudou bastante.